# Get Active Directory group members using PyWin32

Tags: python, pywin32

I need to list all Active Directory group's members - can I do this without using LDAP queries with PyWin's win32security, for instance?

I can lookup accounts' sids and names using it (`LookupAccountSid` and  `LookupAccountName`), but how about getting all group members? For now I cannot figure out what functions I should use.

I have account SID as an input parameter and its Domain name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This [active directory](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/ad_cookbook.html) module wraps an interface around win32com.client.

> active_directory - a lightweight
>   wrapper around COM support  for
>   Microsoft's Active Directory
>
> Active Directory is Microsoft's answer
>   to LDAP, the industry-standard 
>   directory service holding information
>   about users, computers and  other
>   resources in a tree structure,
>   arranged by departments or 
>   geographical location, and optimized
>   for searching.
>
> There are several ways of attaching to
>   Active Directory. This  module uses
>   the Dispatchable LDAP:// objects and
>   wraps them  lightly in helpful Python
>   classes which do a bit of the 
>   otherwise tedious plumbing. The module
>   is quite naive, and  has only really
>   been developed to aid searching, but
>   since  you can always access the
>   original COM object, there's nothing 
>   to stop you using it for any AD
>   operations.